# Generic Method to find the tuples used for aggregation in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table

```
col1 |       name       | pay 
------+------------------+------
    1 | Steve Jobs       | 1006
    2 | Mike Markkula    | 1007
    3 | Mike Scott       | 1978
    4 | John Sculley     | 1983
    5 | Michael Spindler | 1653
```

The user executes a sum query which sums the pay of people getting paid more than $1500. Is there a way to also implicitly know which tuples have been used which satisfy the condition for sum ?

I know you can separately write another query to just return the primary key ids which satisfy the condition. But, Is there any other way to do that in the same query ? probably rewrite the query in some way ? or...

The basic idea is to store references to all tuples which have been used for aggregate queries.
any suggestion ?

Comment: But what would your expected output be in that case? What columns and values do you expect to have in the result?

Comment: Basically I have no control on what queries will be executed in the database. I just want to internally maintain a list of the tuples being refered while executing these queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `array_agg`

```
SELECT sum(pay), array_agg(col1)
FROM salaries
WHERE pay > 1500
```

`array_agg` aggregates values from column into array.

Comment: Bingo. This is exactly what I wanted . Thanks